# Handle private/company wiki from an Android phone

Tags: wiki

I'm currently using the [Oddmuse wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/oddmuse/) to document things, both personal and work related. What I'd like to do is to find an Android app along with a wiki engine which enables me to read and make changes to the wiki with my phone. Using only the browser is unintuitive and hard to use.

How can I do this? I'd rather use [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) or [DokuWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DokuWiki), but I don't know of any apps which can both display and let me log in to edit the wiki.

Comment: I've also looked and have not seen anything available at the moment.

Comment: Hi. I'm late for 3.5 years and your question exactly match what I want too. Have you probably resolved this problem somehow already? I've just found the status page http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Apps regarding the Wikipedia app, but it seems that there is currently no any chance to get this app work for a custom wiki. :(

Answer (score 1):

I am falling in love with [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info). ikiwiki uses [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) which means you can use any text editor to edit your pages.  You can push changes to your server using SVN or git (many other options are also available).

Check out ikiwiki and see if it may be able to provide you with the solution for which you are looking.